# Identifying Road Crossings

Tags: arcgis-desktop, road

**The ingredients:**
I have animal GPS points separated by a certain amount of time
& I have a map of roads... This time could be separated by hours, or days

**The question:**
I want to identify a minimum number of road crossings

**The hard(er) parts:**
*It would be simple(er) to connect the dots with straight lines and look where those lines intersect roads but this can be way off because the line connecting two dots won't necessarily be where the animal crossed the road. I've done this. I want the most accurate idea where the animals are crossing the roads, so I want to narrow down the locations.* What I am looking for is to instead do two things -

1. to put some resistance value on the roads such that lines that connect two wildlife points will cross as few roads as possible (so the line drawn  between two points isn't spanning a great distance and multiple roads).
2. that any line connecting two points can only be X meters long (where X is something like 2km.  If X is not set then the line could be many thousands of km indicating the animal may be trying to avoid crossing a road!).

Comment: If the 'time' is regularly spaced then the maximum distance the animal can travel is limited based on its maximum speed. This sounds like a fairly advanced model.

Comment: What are the time intervals for tracking? Not sure why it would be 'way off' to draw a line between two sequential tracking points, unless you have a huge interval; in that case you might want to do a kernel analysis of home range and see where it intersects with roads.

Comment: This is a really interesting question, but we need to hear more about how your data are collected, and why simply connecting points won't work!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.